# How to display multiple lines as part of the selected option of dropdown in EXTJS

Tags: html, extjs

In Extjs, I have a requirement as below:

When we select an option from the drop down combo, it needs to display the selected option in 2 lines, one below the other.

**Example:** 
On clicking the drop down menu, it would look like this : [Drop down menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xp9hi.png)

### And after selecting an option, currently it looks like this :

### Description (Value)

But is it possible to have it displayed as follows ?

Description

Value

Something like this : [Need-to-be-done : Option selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFynq.png) once the option is selected.

If it is possible, could you please guide how to do so.
To view the source, you can check the below link -

/jorgeramon.me/2016/how-to-customize-the-look-of-an-extjs-combobox/#comment-123438
/github.com/MiamiCoder/ext-js-6-combo-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution I found after a bit of research:

Need to provide fieldSubTpl and setRawValue function in order to render HTML within the displayTpl rather than the HTML tag itself.

And also, increase the min-height or height of the displayTpl in order to display the selected multi-line option, in the appropriate css file

```
*.css file
.custom-panel {
    min-height : 35px;
    height : 35px;
    background-color : white;
}

*.js file

componentCls : 'custom-panel',

displayTpl : Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<tpl for=".">',
    '<div class ="x-combo-item">',
    '<div><span style="float: left;">{description}</span></div><br>',
    '<tpl if="date != \'\'"><div>Est. Delivery:{date}</div></tpl></div>', '</tpl>');

fieldSubTpl: [
    '<div role="presentation"></div>',
    '<div id="{id}" type="{type}" ',
    '<tpl if="size">size="{size}" </tpl>',
    '<tpl if="tabIdx">tabIndex="{tabIdx}" </tpl>',
    'class="{fieldCls} {typeCls}" autocomplete="off"></div>',
    {
        compiled: true
    }
]

setRawValue: function(value) {
    var me = this;
    me.rawValue = value;
    if (me.inputEl) {
        me.inputEl.dom.innerHTML = value;
    }
    return value;
}
```

Hope this is useful for the other inquisitive minds out there.